# Passing a method to Proc in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In Ruby symbol can be conveniently converted to a Proc such as:

```
%{john terry fiona}.map(&:capitalize)   # -> %{John Terry Fiona}
```

Is there a way to pass a method to a Proc, to shorten the following code:

```
["john", "terry", "fiona"].each do |n|
  assert n.valid_encoding?
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: assert %w{john terry fiona}.reject(&:valid_encoding?).empty?

Comment: By the way, it is not possible to pass arguments to Symbol#to_proc calls so you either write it the way you did, create a method in the model or find an other way like I just tried.

Comment: @oldergod, why didn't you post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @jhwist because I did not answer the question, just wrote a one line equivalent of what he was doing.

Comment: you can create a block that allows you to write `["john", "terry", "fiona"].each(&assert_valid_encoding)`, but I don't see the point, the original code is short and clear (use { ... } to write a one-liner if you feel like it).

Comment: @oldergod: "it is not possible to pass arguments to `Symbol#to_proc` calls"... try this: `proc = :+.to_proc; proc.call(1,2)`

Comment: @oldergod You can pass fixed argument with simple extension to `Symbol` class, but obviously not in this case as `n.valid_encoding?` is not really an argument, it's method call. Something like this: `[1,2,3].map(&:+.w_args(3)) #=> [4,5,6]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
%w{john terry fiona}.map(&:valid_encoding?).each(&method(:assert))
```

Answer (score 2):

Unorthodox approach to the same thing:

```
Compose = 
  lambda do |*xs|
    ph, *ps = xs.map(&:to_proc)
    lambda do |*ys|
      r = ph[*ys]
      ps.each do |p|
        r = p[r]
      end
      r
    end
  end

["john", "terry", "fiona"].each(&Compose[:valid_encoding?, method(:assert)])
```